# Diagram for mapping project dependencies or relationships

Tags: requirements, dependencies, visualization, business-process-mapping

Is there a particular diagram established for the mapping of projects that are related? The goal here would be to find a way to make ties between related projects either based on dependencies or requirements. I've found some things on brain mapping a single project but nothing that would show relationships of several projects. Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: ? Gantt Chart? network map?

Comment: I didn't understand if you are looking for a tool or some advice on how to present some kind of roadmap, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What you are looking for is a Visual Portfolio Map

Here is a good article that describes what a Visual Portfolio Map is and why you need one: [How to Manage Interdependencies in a Project Portfolio](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-manage-interdependencies-project-portfolio-don-siler).

> But first, what are these interdependencies and why do they matter to
>   us? They can take a number of forms including (but not limited to) ...
>
> - Resources: Two projects require the same subject matter expert
> - Functionality: One project depends on functionality delivered by another project

Also, you can see links to some research here how a visual map helps the quality of decision making substantially compared to lists and matrices: [The evidence is here: Visual portfolio mapping delivers better decisions](http://governanceandnetworks.blogspot.com/2013/08/the-evidence-is-here-visual-portfolio.html).

> - Map shows the project interdependencies as a social network map. Each project is represented as a circle, color-coded by 'strategic
>     fit', and sized by budget
> - List shows the same information, but in a tabular form
> - Matrix also shows that same information, but as a matrix
>
> The research found that the use of the map was correlated with the
>   highest levels of decision quality. Not just to a small degree, but
>   nearly 3 times better.

Here is an [example of a Visual Portfolio Map](https://www.slideshare.net/Optimice/faster-and-better-project-portfolio-decisions):
[image]

Most PPM (Project Portfolio Management) software will have the capability to create some variation of this diagram.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. I upvoted but I'm new to the site and it isn't displayed :( Thank you for your very thorough response.

Comment: As the person who asked the question, you should be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the materials:

1. A board where you can stick pins
2. Index cards for stories
3. String & pins

Process:

1. Break down your requirements to user stories (vertical slices through your tech stack that DELIVER VALUE TO YOUR USERS) and add these to your board.
2. Find out which ones have dependencies outside your team/project.
3. Use pins and string to draw a line to another project where the dependency is.

When you're ready, take a picture.